# Изменение байтовой строки python

Tags: python, строки, byte

Есть байтовая строка: `b'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00'`
Как из неё сделать: `b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать такой прием:

```
b = b'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00'
result = b.decode("unicode-escape").encode("latin1")
print(result)  # Вывод: b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00'
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!